# Preview pdf instead of download using Rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I am trying to print `.html` file as `.pdf` file using Rotativa. I have tried this code:

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Index") { FileName = "Product.pdf" };
```

My index action is here:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}
```

But, the generated `.pdf` file is downloaded instead of previewed. I don't want to download it. I want the preview and then print it.

Comment: hmm, I think Rotativa only behaves as a pdf converter, but previewing a file depends if your browser has a acrobat reader or something like this that lets you preview your documents on your local machine http://groupdocs.com/apps/viewer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer.I need to remove the `FileName` attribute.If I want to download it, I need to add the FileName attribute and if I want to see just the preview, I need to remove this.The code should be just :

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Index");
```